# Problems resizing UILabel inside custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to create a `UITableViewCell` with many items inside but I have problems with `UILabels`.

When using default Styles for `UITableViewCell`, `TextLabel` and `DetailTextLabel` just get properly height to fit content, and I only have to use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to calculate `row height`.

But with my custom `cell`, `UILabels` don't `resize` their height, always keep the `size` I set on the interface builder, i'm trying this

```
    CGRect frame;    
    cell.title.text = item.title;
    frame.origin = cell.title.frame.origin;
    frame.size = [item.title sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17]
                       constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(FB_Cell_width, 4000) lineBreakMode:cell.title.lineBreakMode];

    cell.title.frame = frame;
```

But the `UILabel` size doesn't change.

I try:

```
cell.title.text = item.title;
[cell.title sizeToFit];
```

But size still doesn't change.

How and where I need to change the `UILabel` frame to fit its content?

**EDIT:** I just untick the use autolayout option and now it seems to work.

Comment: Maybe autoresizing masks could help. Or maybe you could use `sizeWithFont`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 UILabel *title =  [[UILabel alloc]init]; 
 title.numberOfLines = 0;  
 title.text = item.title;
 float height =  [self heightForText:title.text];
 title.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 40, height);
 [cell addSubView:title];
}

- (CGFloat)heightForText:(NSString *)bodyText
{
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(500, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [bodyText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    CGFloat height = labelSize.height + 10;
    return height;
}

//try it like this may be it will helps u
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
cell.title.numberOfLines = 0; //makes your label of unlimited numberoflines
cell.title.text = item.title;
[cell.title sizeToFit];
```

Comment: numberOfLines property is set to 0 on Interface Builder

Comment: `[[cell title] setText:item.title];`  
`[[cell title] sizeToFit];`